# Most up-to-date stats

Tags: exchanges

Where are the most realtime (up to date) stats for exchanges like mtgox? For basic stats like exchange rate and volume, what is the best, average, and worst-case reporting delay and what's the URL?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+exchange+chart

Answer (score 1):

I find http://bitcoincharts.com to be of high quality.